# Intellisense errors when switching from Visual Studio 2013 back to 2012

Tags: c, opengl, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have an OpenGL application that ran without any errors when I was using Visual Studio 2013. Now my license for VS2013 is expired and I switched back to VS2012. When I open the project in VS2012, I get tons of errors:

```
    41  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 96  64  comp410_hw1
    42  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 100 63  comp410_hw1
    43  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 104 63  comp410_hw1
    44  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 108 63  comp410_hw1
    45  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 112 63  comp410_hw1
    46  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 116 63  comp410_hw1
    47  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 120 63  comp410_hw1
    48  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\Halil\Desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 124 63  comp410_hw1
Error   5   error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 97  1   comp410_hw1
Error   10  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 101 1   comp410_hw1
Error   15  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 105 1   comp410_hw1
Error   20  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 109 1   comp410_hw1
Error   25  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 113 1   comp410_hw1
Error   30  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 117 1   comp410_hw1
Error   35  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 121 1   comp410_hw1
Error   40  error C2181: illegal else without matching if   c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 125 1   comp410_hw1
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 96  1   comp410_hw1
Error   8   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 100 1   comp410_hw1
Error   13  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 104 1   comp410_hw1
Error   18  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 108 1   comp410_hw1
Error   23  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 112 1   comp410_hw1
Error   28  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 116 1   comp410_hw1
Error   33  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 120 1   comp410_hw1
Error   38  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 124 1   comp410_hw1
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 96  1   comp410_hw1
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 100 1   comp410_hw1
Error   12  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 104 1   comp410_hw1
Error   17  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 108 1   comp410_hw1
Error   22  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 112 1   comp410_hw1
Error   27  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 116 1   comp410_hw1
Error   32  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 120 1   comp410_hw1
Error   37  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 124 1   comp410_hw1
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 96  1   comp410_hw1
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 100 1   comp410_hw1
Error   11  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 104 1   comp410_hw1
Error   16  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 108 1   comp410_hw1
Error   21  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 112 1   comp410_hw1
Error   26  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 116 1   comp410_hw1
Error   31  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 120 1   comp410_hw1
Error   36  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'  c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 124 1   comp410_hw1
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 96  1   comp410_hw1
Error   9   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 100 1   comp410_hw1
Error   14  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 104 1   comp410_hw1
Error   19  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 108 1   comp410_hw1
Error   24  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 112 1   comp410_hw1
Error   29  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 116 1   comp410_hw1
Error   34  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 120 1   comp410_hw1
Error   39  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\halil\desktop\comp410_hw1\comp410_hw1\main.cpp 124 1   comp410_hw1
```

All of these errors belong to this piece of code:

```
void setColor()
{
    switch (currentColor)
    {
    case COLOR_RED:
        if (lightOn) {glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0});}
        else glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case COLOR_GREEN:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case COLOR_BLUE:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        break;
    case COLOR_CYAN:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        break;
    case COLOR_MAGENTA:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        break;
    case COLOR_YELLOW:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case COLOR_PURPLE:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.5);
        break;
    case COLOR_ORANGE:
        if (lightOn) glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, new GLfloat[] { 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0});
        else glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);
        break;
    }
}
```

What I first thought was the header files were making a mess, so I put them in every possible order but these stupid errors remain.

Comment: Intelisense holds some information in project files *.sdf, try to remove it and then reopen and recompile project.

Comment: Nope it didn't work unfortunately. I still get the same errors when I delete .sdf file and clean the project.

Comment: Just noticed, you are using c++, wright? Construction like this: `new GLfloat[] { 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0}` is illegal. Create those arrays normally, as static size array, with initializing list (`GLfloata[] = { 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f}; glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, a);`), or dynamically, and then, fill them with values.

Comment: That is actually what a friend of mine suggested, and it makes sense that it would be illegal. However when I was running this project on VS2013, it didn't cause a problem. Is it because of the different compilers they use? Does/can that change the acceptable syntax of the language?

Comment: I changed the code the way you told me to and it works just fine now. Thank you. But I'm still confused about this behaviour. If you know what's causing this, please let me know.

Comment: Well, it seems, that VS13 implement c++11 better than VS12, because such a method of initialisation is available in c++11.